# Windows Phone 8.1 CloseDisplayMode is ignored in landscape mode

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I noticed the ClosedDisplayMode setting is ignored when the screen is rotated to landscape. The BottomAppBar will start minimized but will then expand automatically in landscape and then minimize again in portrait. How do I keep the ClosedDisplayMode set to "minimal" for both portrait and landscape? Thanks in advance!

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal" >
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton 
                Label="About" 
                Click="AppBarButton_Click" 
                Icon="Help"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: I thought it was a bug in my code - thanks for confirming that it's a bug in WP8.1

Comment: I am so new to WP in general that I assumed I was doing something wrong. A bug in WP8.1 makes more sense. Thanks for the feedback and for giving me a little bit of my sanity back. :)